# Scroll to top in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have 100 messages i want to display initially latest 10 (means last 10) messages after scrolling to top i need to display previous 10 messages vice versa how to do it in angularjs

```
 <div class="chat-box-content" ng-repeat="chat in chatMsgs">
      <div class="user-chat">
        <p>{{chat.msg}}</p>
      </div>
  </div
```

Comment: You can do it by making directive.

Comment: how to do with directive give me any example if you know

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/611/).

When scrolling to top `loadMoreChatFn()` will call where you can load previous 10 messages.

please see the console window in jsfiddle.